# Is tabindex hack for CSS :focus specified somewhere?

Tags: html, css, specifications, w3c, tabindex

There is a hack to make work `:focus` pseudoclass for `div` elements: adding to `div` `tabindex`. Like this:

```css
.testFocus:focus{
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="testFocus" tabindex="0">awesomeDiv</div>
```

Is this behavior specified somewhere in W3C documents (where?) or is it just a non-documented hack?

"This behavior" consists of:

1. `div` element is not focusable by default.
2. `div` element with `tabindex` is focusable.

Comment: W3C HTML5 and WHATWG HTML don't outright state whether tabindex can be applied to any element or whether it only applies to certain elements. (Most third-party sources claim that it's a global attribute, though.) But what they do state, is that tabindex grants an element focusability, which for the purposes of Selectors means that element matches :focus when it's in focus.

Comment: @BoltClock, thanks, with Korgrue link it is now clear for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tabindex` is one of the [global attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/dom.html#sec-global-attributes). This means it can be specified on all HTML elements.

`0` is a valid value (see "If the value is a zero" under the [definition of `tabindex`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/editing.html#the-tabindex-attribute)).

So your HTML is fine.

Comment: Question is not about how fine my HTML, it is more about "why tabindex connected to :focus such strange (for me) way?" and "why the hell browsers behavior differs here? Should not it be specified?"

Comment: @Mr.Duck: What is strange about it? The `tabindex` attribute with the value `0` makes an element focusable. If it’s focusable, the CSS pseudo class `:focus` fires.

Comment: it is not intuitive for me, that tabindex should make element focusable. It is no intuitive, that lot of elements not focusable buy default. Thats why i asked for specification reference

Comment: @Mr.Duck: I linked to the section where `tabindex` is defined, which also defines what the value `0` means. The same section defines which elements are focusable by default.

Comment: yeah thanx, but i already got this link from Korgrue, and and spec interpretation from BoltClock)

Comment: @Mr.Duck: Yes, but note that the link in Korgrue’s answer goes to HTML5 (old REC), while my link goes to HTML 5.1 (current REC). I posted an answer because Korgrue’s claim is not correct (`tabindex` doesn’t only work on the quoted elements, see my comment there). The answer also doesn’t state that `tabindex` can be used on any element, and that `0` is a valid value (so no "hack").

Answer (score 0):

tabindex will work on the following elements in HTML5.   https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute

> - a elements that have an href attribute
> - link elements that have an href attribute
> - button elements
> - input elements whose type attribute are not in the Hidden state
> - select elements
> - textarea elements

Comment: So is it specified as "suggestion" not as "claim"?

Comment: These are the elements which should get the tabindex focus flag by default (if no `tabindex` is specified, or if its value is invalid).