# Dynamically created li will not .focus() on click

Tags: jquery

```
$('#spell-check').on('click', 'li', function() { 
  $(this).focus()
});

<ul id="spell-check">
  <li tabindex="1">suggestion 2</li>
  <li tabindex="2">suggestion 1</li>
</ul>
```

The `<li>`'s are added dynamically to this list, but the `<ul id="spell-check">` is included on load.
The problem is that the `<li>` will not focus after it is clicked. What am I doing wrong please?

**This is an edit**
I have just discovered that the issue is that I didn't have any css applied for the focus like:

```
#spell-check li:focus {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

But what I can't understand is why when the li is focused did the chrome browser styling not apply on this occasion? Because when I focussed the same element based on a keystroke event it did apply the chrome blue border without adding the :focus css?

So the (standard Chrome) focused blue border was applied when I did:

```
$('input').on('keyup', function(e) {
   var $spellSuggestList = $("#spell-check");
   if (e.keyCode == 40) {
     $("li:first-child", $spellSuggestList).focus();
     return
   }
})
```

Anyway, I don't know if it's appropriate, but it might help someone else one day.

Comment: Provide a minimum, working example that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why \`div:focus does\` not works without tabindex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49981814/why-divfocus-does-not-works-without-tabindex)

Comment: *"Because when I focussed the same element based on a keystroke event it did apply the chrome blue border without adding the :focus css?"* Does this do something different than what I thoght it did? `$("li:first-child", $spellSuggestList).focus();`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `tabindex` attribute to the dynamically created `<li>`. Working example:

```js
$('#spell-check').on('click', 'li', function() { 
  $(this).focus()
});
$('#spell-check').append('<li tabindex="-1">foobar</li>')
```

```css
:focus {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul id="spell-check">
  <li tabindex="1">suggestion 2</li>
  <li tabindex="2">suggestion 1</li>
</ul>
```

Reference: [Why `div:focus does` not works without tabindex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49981814/why-divfocus-does-not-works-without-tabindex)